# make two div is inline on dompdf

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sticker using dompdf. They looked like this :
[image: Sticker Report].

I use inline-block towo create two div's in line, but not working.
My code in dompdf like this :

```
.left{
            width : 50%;
            height : 100px;
            border: solid 2px black;
            display : inline-block;

        }

        .left p{
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align : center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            line-height: 100px
        }

        .right{
            width : 50%;
            height: 100px;
            border: solid 2px black;
            background-color: red;

        }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <?php
       $i = 1;
       foreach ($detail as $val):
   ?>

       <div class="left">
           <p><?php echo $val['no_urut'] ?></p>
           <p><?php echo $val['thick'] . '-' . $val['contract_no'] ?></p>
           <p><?php echo $val['coil_no'] ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="right">
           <p><?php echo $val['no_urut'] ?></p>
           <p><?php echo $val['thick'] . '-' . $val['contract_no'] ?></p>
           <p><?php echo $val['coil_no'] ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
            $i++;
            endforeach;
        ?>
     </div>
```

I get this on the result :
[image: For the solution is so appreciated]

Comment: In dompdf I'd recommend you to use tables to build this layout...

Answer (score 0):

```
.left{
            float: left;
            width : 50%;
            height : 100px;
            border: solid 2px black;
            display : inline-block;

        }
        .right{
            float: right;
            width : 50%;
            height: 100px;
            border: solid 2px black;
            background-color: red;

        }
```